# get value od radio button created in doGet()

Tags: java, jsp, post, get, radio-button

I have created radiobuttons in doGet method:

```
 <c:forEach items="${questions}" var="question">
               <li>
                ${question.value}
                <label><input type="radio" name="${question.key}" value="yes"> Yes</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="${question.key}" value="no"> No</label> <br/>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
```

and these create correctly. When I try to read the selected value of the radio button I get `null`

I read them with:

```
 if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getParameter(QUESTION + "" + String.valueOf(questionIndex)))) {
                answer = "1";
            }
```

I also get `nulls` when I just check the value with `System.out`

```
        System.out.println("q0: "+ req.getParameter("q0"));
        System.out.println("q1: "+ req.getParameter("q1"));
        System.out.println("q2: "+ req.getParameter("q2"));
        System.out.println("q3: "+ req.getParameter("q3"));
```

Do you have any ideas why I get `nulls` when I want to read the value in `doPost()`?

**EDIT:**
This is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <form method="GET" action="keywords">
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="${questions}" var="question">
               <li>
                ${question.value}
                <label><input type="radio" name="${question.key}" value="yes">Yes</label>
                <label><input type="radio" name="${question.key}" value="no">No</label> <br/>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
<div>
    <form method="POST" action="keywords">
        <input type="submit" value="Search Keywords">
    </form>
</div>
```

I guess the issue here is that the form I am trying to read is not inside `<form>` with method `POST`, is that right?
How to change the HTML code so that in `doPost` I am able to read the form I have in `doGet`.

I hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

Map is from a json file:

```
   public static final String QUESTION = "q";
    Map<String, String> questionsMap;

    public Map<String, String> createQuestionsMap() {
        questionsMap = new TreeMap<>();
        JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader();
        jsonReader.readQuestionJsonArray();
        LOGGER.info(MARKER, "Invoked questions map.");
        for (String question : jsonReader.readQuestionJsonArray()) {
            questionsMap.put(QUESTION + "" + questionsMap.size(), question);
            LOGGER.info(MARKER,
                    "Added question record: " + QUESTION + "" + questionsMap.size() + ", question: " + question);
        }
        return questionsMap;
    }
```

the id is like `q1`, `q2`, etc. ...

All *questions* and all *ids* are correctly displaying in the `HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need Javascript for this. Maybe a little help of jQuery.

When you click on the submit button in post form, instead of the default action copy over the values from the get form and then post with it.

Comment: Of course if you can make the button and inputs under the same `<form>` you don't need to jump over hoops.